Makefile: condition on specific target
In my ideal solution, I want a Makefile that set sanitizers based on SAN variable, only when I call the target "debug", and take care that, as now, gcc do not support -fsanitize=memory, so pass only when CC=clang
The first try was:
...
CC=gcc # gcc|clang
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2
SAN?=address # address|thread|memory

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN)

debug: all
   CFLAGS+=-g -fsanitize=undefined
   LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=undefined
   ifeq ($(SAN),address)
      CFLAGS+=-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined
      LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined
   endif
   ifeq ($(SAN),thread)
      CFLAGS+=-fsanitize=thread
      LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=thread
   endif
   ifeq ($(SAN),memory)
      ifeq ($(CC),clang)
         CFLAGS+=-fsanitize=memory -fPIE -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize-memory-track-origins
         LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=memory -fPIE -pie
      endif
   endif

but doesn't work.
Then I try something more simple without the SAN variable like:
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2

debug: CFLAGS+=-g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined
debug: LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined
debug: all
ifeq ($(CC),clang)
   CFLAGS+=-fsanitize=memory -fPIE -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize-memory-track-origins
   LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=memory -fPIE -pie
endif

but stil not work.
Work this but it is really too simple:
debug: CFLAGS+=-g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined
debug: LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined
debug: all

suggestions?

You don't say what "it doesn't work" actually means.  Please show the command you invoked, and cut and paste the errors you got.  Also it's helpful to provide the version of GNU Make you're using and the OS you're building on.
Are you imagining that somehow by indenting some lines after a target like debug: all, that those are make variable assignments which are only relevant to the target debug?  That's not at all how make works.  To understand makefile syntax you can read the docs.
This:
debug: all
   CFLAGS+=-g -fsanitize=undefined
   LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=undefined

Is exactly the same (as far as make is concerned) to writing:
   CFLAGS+=-g -fsanitize=undefined
   LDFLAGS+=-fsanitize=undefined

debug: all

(or any other combination).  That's assuming of course that the indentation here is just spaces, not a TAB character: it's not clear from your question.  If you'd shown us the errors you got it would be clear, since those lines are not valid shell script lines.
One option to do what you want is this:
CFLAGS_address = -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined
LDFLAGS_address = -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined

CFLAGS_thread = -fsanitize=thread
LDFLAGS_thread = -fsanitize=thread

ifeq ($(CC),clang)
  CFLAGS_memory = -fsanitize=memory -fPIE -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize-memory-track-origins
  LDFLAGS_memory = -fsanitize=memory -fPIE -pie
endif

debug: CFLAGS += -g -fsanitize=undefined $(CFLAGS_$(SAN))
debug: LDFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined $(LDFLAGS_$(SAN))
debug: all


thank you. From the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Assignment.html#index-conditional-variable-assignment and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html I had the impression that assignments could be conditioned even within targets. GNU make 4.3 on Debian 12. Your solution solve most of my needs. The last one is that I want to set -O3 in all targets, but set -O2 in debug target

The first example shows a conditional assignment of a make variable, but it's not in the context of a target.  The second shows a conditional, but it's not a variable assignment it's a shell comment.  You can't combine them and infer that it's also valid to conditionally assign make variables in the context of targets.  Lines after a target that do not begin with TAB characters are simply other make lines, they are not "part of" the target.  And lines after a target that DO begin with TAB characters are shell commands, not makefile lines (like make variable assignments).

There are many ways to reset the optimization level.  One simple one is to rely on the fact that GCC allows you to set the -O option multiple times and uses the last value.  So, you can just use: debug: CFLAGS += -O2 and that will override the -O3 that's in the global assignment of CFLAGS.

I saw this is valid for clang too, so thanks
